# Intent not working always as expected

Tags: java, android, android-intent

There are two flows in my app.

**Flow 1:**

**Splash Screen --> Activity A --> Activity B --> Activity C --> Activity A**

**Flow 2:**

**Splash Screen --> Activity C --> Activity A**

To explain the above; in **Flow 1** a user sees the splash screen, goes to home screen, goes to login screen and on successful login, goes to main screen. If the user hits logout from the main screen he is redirected to the home screen.

In **Flow 2** the user is an old user, he sees the splash screen and directly sees the main screen. If he logs out he should be directed to the home screen.

The problem which I am facing is that, in Flow 1, everything is working as expected. But in Flow 2, after logout (Activity C), the home screen (Activity A) is not opening. The intent is not working.

**On click logout:**

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((StudyStoryMain)getActivity()).logoutUser();
            }
```

**The Method:**

```
public void logoutUser() {
        //Problem: the intent is getting called in case the user creates an account. But, if the user is already an existing user, the intent is nit working
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        ParseUser.logOut();
        Intent i = new Intent(StudyStoryMain.this, HomeActivity.class);
        //logic to fix logout
//      i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        finish();
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

**Why is the Intent not working in both the flows?**

Comment: try to move startActivity(i) before finish().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(StudyStoryMain.this, HomeActivity.Class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // Call once you redirect to another activity
```

Comment: @kittu88 Can you please check the logcat for any exceptions or warnings that occured while calling the activity?

Answer (score 0):

Before finishing current Activity start another Activity :

```
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

As in logoutUser() method you are calling finish() before startActivity() which is wrong as startActivity(intent) get never call.
So just change sequence to

```
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

Comment: Tried, not a solution to the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((StudyStoryMain)getActivity()).logoutUser();
                 finish();
            }
```

The Method:

```
public void logoutUser() {
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        ParseUser.logOut();
        Intent i = new Intent(StudyStoryMain.this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Try this way, hope it solves your problem.

Comment: logoutUser() is in different activity? Try to keep the method on the same activity where logout button is clicked.

Comment: logoutUser() is in the activity where the fragment lies, basically logout functionality is in a fragment. I had already tried with having the method in the fragment as well! Just can not figure out the cause of this disobedience with the method!